# Trying to find this cyborg movie I watched sometime in early 2010s

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

I think the movie was released around that time (early 2010s, maybe late 2000s, I know it was at least before 2013) but I’m not entirely sure.

Basically all I remember is there was this boy and girl, and this cyborg was protecting them but it was actually an evil cyborg that was rehabilitated or something. And then near the end of the movie there was a dialog like “I was good but you turned me bad” from this cyborg and he was chasing the kids slowly.

Honestly I just remember that quote from time to time and get really annoyed that I can’t figure it out. I remember it being sad like that word-for-word but I might not have watched it in English so I’m not fully sure if my memory just translated it or what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any other things you can remember?  Was it set in contemporary times (with respect to when it was released)?  Approximate age of the children?  Nature of the enemy that the cyborg was protecting the children from?

Comment: Hm, Anakin Skywalker?

Comment: see if anything here rings a bell: https://ultimateactionmovies.com/best-cyborg-action-movies/

Comment: I'm pretty certain it was set in the future, children were very young, like 8-10 (maybe?). I don't remember too much about the enemy. Also, I checked through that list and I don't think it is any of those.Sorry for the late reply, I don't ask on stack exchange too often and assumed that since I didn't get notifications that no one saw my question lol.